# How to Segue-Push after using UISearchBar in a TableView, project with storyboard

Tags: storyboard, push, tableview, uisearchbar, segue

I have a UITableView with a UISearchBar in a project that uses storyboard.

The search function without problem.

I have the cell linked to a Seague Push to the next view.

If I select a cell, the next view is loaded and everything works perfect.

Everything was perfect until I use UISearchBar, then stops working Segue Push and I can not go to the next view when I select the filtered cell.

What to do? Force segue.

A model of a project at this links:

http://uploaded.to/file/ooohrxnf

```
//Code for search
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{

[searchData removeAllObjects];

NSArray *group;

for(group in arraynumbers)
{
    NSMutableArray *newGroup = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *element;

    for(element in group)
    {
        NSRange range = [element rangeOfString:searchString options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (range.length > 0) {
            [newGroup addObject:element];
        }
    }

    if ([newGroup count] > 0) {
        [searchData addObject:newGroup];
    }        
}

onTableData = searchData;

return YES;
}

// Force Segue when UISearchBar isActive
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (self.searchDisplayController.isActive) {


    NSMutableArray *mutablerray = [searchData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];        
    number = [mutablerray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];       
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detail" sender:self];
    searchBar.text = @"";
}

}

// pickup number when UISearchBar isNotActive and reloadData after Segue
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detail"])
{
    if (!self.searchDisplayController.isActive) 
    {

        number = [[onTableData objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] section]] objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
    }

    NSLog(@"number: %@", number);
    [segue.destinationViewController setNumber:number];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue, and ended up trying a variety of things since the UISearchDisplayController was very new to me. I ended up setting the tableView as the searchResultsDelegate for the searchDisplayController:

```
searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
```

I'm not quite sure why this took care of it though. Anyone with an explanation?

Comment: Please add ' or four spaces when you add code to your answer. '<code>' or four spaces <code>.